# Expo React Native Node.js version 11.12.0 is no longer supported. How to fix?

Tags: node.js, react-native, terminal, expo, node-modules

I'm using Expo for my React Native project and everything ran perfectly fine until I updated the Expo using 'npm install -g expo-cli'. After I ran this on my terminal and tried to run my project again using 'expo start' I got this error.

```
ERROR: Node.js version 11.12.0 is no longer supported.

expo-cli supports following Node.js versions:
* >=8.9.0 <9.0.0 (Maintenance LTS)
* >=10.13.0 <11.0.0 (Active LTS)
* >=12.0.0 (Current Release)
```

I checked my node version, npm version, and my expo cli version. 
Which respectively was v11.12.0, 6.7.0, and ^2.17.1

[image]
[image]

**Methods I've used**

1) I've used brew upgrade node
2) I did '`$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.1/install.sh | bash'` to install nvm and then I did 'nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=node' to get the latest version but it said command not found and nothing worked.
3) I don't want to use 'sudo npm install -g n' and
'sudo n latest' because I'm afraid how that might negatively impact npm.

**QUESTION**

How do I fix this? Or if possible how do i go back to my old expo version?

Comment: Having the same issue, did you find a fix?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to fix this would be to upgrade to the supported version of Node.js. I don't know If anyone else knows a better solution than this. And I believe you can transfer your project over. Good luck.